# Does it make sense to regularly switch jobs to wash away any past mistakes?

Tags: job-search

This is currently a hypothetical, but does it make sense to switch jobs every two years to wipe away the blemishes (mistakes, things you forgot, etc) and start fresh? As when you move jobs, you only take the positives, I.e what is on your resume.

Comment: I common interview question is "Tell me about a time you made a mistake and what you did about it." If your best answer is "I switched jobs", that isn't going to look good for you. Everyone makes mistakes, it's what you do about them that is important.

Comment: You would only ever include positives on your resume so I'm not clear on why that would require changing jobs on a specific schedule.

Comment: `does it make sense to switch jobs every two years to wipe away the blemishes (mistakes, things you forgot, etc) and start fresh?` - No. No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

As you get further into your career, it will become apparent to any potential employer that you keep switching jobs every two years.

At that point, nobody will want to employ you for anything but a temporary or unskilled job.  There will be no point, as they know you are only going to leave again after a couple of years.  Recruiting new people is expensive, and they don't want to waste their money.

Comment: There are businesses that would look past heavy job hopping and still make an offer.  The problem is that they're dumpsterfires whose working conditions are awful enough that they lose most hires within a year or two; and are desperate to get butts in seats any way they can.  OTOH those are just about the last places you want to be working.

Comment: Yes JBoss hopping can be negative. However 2-3 previous employments with a stay time of each 2 years is quite normal. Something you would expect from job starters.

Answer (score 1):

A large part of experience in a career is learning from your mistakes. Everybody makes mistakes.  Wise people learn from them and know to avoid them in the future.

So, in my opinion, starting over from scratch after you've made some mistakes is a good way to pretend you're inexperienced.  Experienced people are more valuable than inexperienced people. So pretending to be inexperienced is cheating yourself and your employer.

In other words, you asked

> Does it make sense to regularly switch jobs to wash away any past mistakes?

And my answer is no, no, a thousand times no.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't make sense.

Incompetence follows you eventually and chances for advancement are slim if you keep moving. Realistically if you expect to be making enough errors that you need to leave in 2 years as your reputation is in tatters. You're better off fixing the underlying issues leading to the errors.

Having said that, I have seen whole careers work this way.